# Adding a custom/dynamic attribute when using XSD.exe

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I am using xsd.exe to generate a C# class that will be used to serialize data to XML. However one of the attributes that I have for a tag is dynamic.

ex:

```
<foo cat="onething">
or
<foo dog="something">
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way to make attribute names dynamic is to account for any attribute. After you create your XML Schema, *add* an `<xs:anyAttribute>` attribute in the XSD file and *then generate* your class.

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Project">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Mark">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedByte">
              <xs:attribute name="IsLate" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:attribute name="MadeEarlyDeadline" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
              <xs:anyAttribute/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Your xml object class will have an `XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr' property. Any new attribute that isn't defined in the XML object will appear in this property when you deserialize, but when you serialize, it will appear as a new attribute.

Serialization Example... let's say the person 'cheated' in the project.

```
        xmlProject project = new xmlProject();

        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        XmlAttribute cheated = xd.CreateAttribute("Cheated");
        cheated.Value = "Yes";

        XmlAttribute[] xa = new XmlAttribute[]{ cheated };

        project.Mark = new xmlProjectMark() { IsLate = "Yes", MadeEarlyDeadline = "False", AnyAttr = xa, Value=70 };
        project.Name = "Jonathan";

        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlProject));

        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
        writer.Serialize(file, project);
        file.Close();
```

The above will give you something like this:

```
<xmlProject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Jonathan</Name>
  <Mark IsLate="Yes" MadeEarlyDeadline="False" Cheated="Yes">70</Mark>
</xmlProject>
```

And to deserialize:

```
        XmlDocument xd2 = new XmlDocument();
        xd2.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xmlProject));
        xmlProject deserializedProject = (xmlProject)xs.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xd2.DocumentElement));
```

Sorry for the long answer, hope it solves your requirements... :)

Comment: So the issue I have is that, using your example, "isLateField" and "MadeEarlyDeadline" can have dynamic names. They might be called that now, but in the future... they can change.